# Is it possible to configure Paypal's Node SDK with an authToken instead of a client ID / secret?

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

We have a situation where our users will be logging into Paypal and then paying other people from their Paypal account via our dashboard. We have the connection setup to retrieve refresh & authTokens for them via `simple-oauth2` module. What I don't see is how to utilize a token in the Paypal Node SDK. It seems to only support client id and secret configurations.

Is there a way to utilize the `paypal.configuration` with an authToken instead?

Should we be using the REST APIs directly instead of the SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly transfer amount to other people account.

You firstly need to transact it into your own buisness account and then you can transfer it to any other person account.